# SilverStripe blog module translation

Tags: content-management-system, silverstripe

I noticed that the blog module for SS have hardcoded pieces of text - that I need to translate (in french). I found that the code is in /blog/templates/Includes/BlogSummary.ss but when I modify it, nothing changes on front-end...

I tried to run a /dev/build/?flush=all but nothing... still.

Any idea? Help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you added the ?flush=All to the page in question itself?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your locale?  I recently set up a site in English & Spanish and used this setup.

```
//  add similar code to your _config.php file
#Translatable::set_default_locale('en_US'); 
#Translatable::set_allowed_locales(array( 
#   'en_US',
#   'es_US'
#));
```

Further, I had to add i18n::set_locale() code to the init() function in my content controller to get the template translations to work.

```
<?php

class SmartLanguageExtension extends DataObjectDecorator {

    function contentcontrollerInit() {
        i18n::set_locale(Translatable::get_current_locale());
    }

}
```

In my case, I added an extension to the Page_Controller class for reusability later on.

```
//  _config.php file
Object::add_extension('Page', 'SmartLanguageExtension');
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! 

In fact, I should have mentioned that I'm not using Translatable module.

I found the solution! Since I am building my first SS site, I did not had a /silverstripe-cache/ folder to my site (never saw that step in any docs I've read). Now I can manually delete the cache to see the result of my changes.

One question left... Why this folder is not part of the SS installation package...? Still a mystery.

Comment: Also, I don't know where the cached files were going before I made the folder. But one sure thing, cached files were created.